# Conditional onTapGesture in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, editmode

I have a navigation link and I need a different behavior when its label (`MyView`) is tapped depending on the edit mode (or any other condition):

1. If we are **not** in edit mode, I want to trigger the navigation link and show the `DetailView` with the selected model.
2. If we are in edit mode, I don't want to trigger the navigation link and show an `EditingView` in a modal sheet instead.

Here's a way to implement this that I came up with:

```
NavigationLink(tag: model, selection: $displayedItem) {
    DetailView(model: model)
} label: {
    if editMode == .active {
        MyView()
            .onTapGesture {
                editingModel = model
            }
    } else {
        MyView()
    }
}
.sheet(item: $editingModel) { model in
    EditingView(model: model)
}
```

The problem with this approach is that the views in the if- and the else-branch have not the same type (due to the `onTapGesture` modifier) and SwiftUI doesn't recognize them as the same view. Thus, animations cannot be interpolated and don't work properly. Also, `MyView` always loses its state each time `editMode` is toggled.

(Here's a great explanation from Chris Eidhof on why that happens: https://www.objc.io/blog/2021/08/24/conditional-view-modifiers/)

So I went ahead and moved the if-statement inside the `onTapGesture` modifier as follows so that I don't have two different `MyView`s:

```
NavigationLink(tag: model, selection: $displayedItem) {
    DetailView(model: model)
} label: {
    MyView()
        .onTapGesture {
            if editMode == .active { // moved
                editingModel = model
            }                        // moved
        }
    }
}
.sheet(item: $editingModel) { model in
    EditingView(model: model)
}
```

Problem with this is that now requirement #1 doesn't work anymore: The `onTapGesture` completely swallow the tap gesture and thus the navigation link is never trigged to show the `DetailView`. Makes sense.

Now my question is:

### How can I get the desired behavior without any of these downsides?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short, you want to change:

```
if editMode == .active {
    MyView()
        .onTapGesture {
            editingModel = model
        }
} else {
    MyView()
}
```

Into:

```
MyView()
    .allowsHitTesting(editMode == .active)
    .onTapGesture {
        editingModel = model
    }
```

This fixes the issue because now the `onTapGesture` is only triggered when it can actually listen to touches. It can only trigger when `editMode == .active`, because otherwise the hit testing is disabled.

---

Full example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var displayedItem: String?
    @State private var editingModel: EditingModel?
    @State private var editMode: EditMode = .inactive

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Button("Edit mode: \(editMode == .active ? "active" : "inactive")") {
                    if editMode == .active {
                        editMode = .inactive
                    } else {
                        editMode = .active
                    }
                }

                NavigationLink(tag: "model", selection: $displayedItem) {
                    Text("DetailView")
                } label: {
                    if editMode == .active {
                        MyView()
                            .onTapGesture {
                                editingModel = EditingModel(tag: "model")
                            }
                    } else {
                        MyView()
                    }
                }
                .sheet(item: $editingModel) { model in
                    Text("EditingView: \(model.tag)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("MyView")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
    }
}
```

```
struct EditingModel: Identifiable {
    var id: String { tag }
    let tag: String
}
```

Changing the inner label bit to:

```
MyView()
    .allowsHitTesting(editMode == .active)
    .onTapGesture {
        editingModel = EditingModel(tag: "model")
    }
```

Comment: Great answer! Straightforward and simple. Thanks! One could go ahead and wrap the hit-test modifier and the tap gesture modifier into a single modifier to make it more expressive of what's happening.

Answer (score 3):

Building on George's suggestion, I ended up with the following custom modifier:

```
extension View {
    func onTapGestureIf(_ condition: Bool, closure: @escaping () -> ()) -> some View {
        self.allowsHitTesting(condition)
            .onTapGesture {
                closure()
            }
    }
}
```

Works like a charm and this way, I don't have to specify the same condition `editMode == .active` twice (single source of truth). Highly recommended.

```
MyView()
    .onTapGestureIf(editMode == .active) {
        editingCounter = counter
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **Group** to wrap onTapGesture. That's it.

```swift
extension View {
  public func onTapGesture(isOn: Bool, count: Int = 1, perform action: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
    Group {
      if isOn {
        self.onTapGesture(count: count, perform: action)
      } else {
        self
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom modifier.

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var displayedItem: String?
@State private var editingModel: EditingModel?
@State private var editMode: EditMode = .inactive
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            Button("Edit mode: \(editMode == .active ? "active" : "inactive")") {
                if editMode == .active {
                    editMode = .inactive
                } else {
                    editMode = .active
                }
            }
            
            NavigationLink(tag: "model", selection: $displayedItem) {
                Text("DetailView")
            } label: {
                MyView()
                    .modifier(conditionalTapGesture(editMode: $editMode, editingModel: $editingModel))
            }
            .sheet(item: $editingModel) { model in
                Text("EditingView: \(model.tag)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
struct conditionalTapGesture : ViewModifier {
    @Binding var editMode: EditMode
    @Binding var editingModel: EditingModel?
    @ViewBuilder func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if editMode == .active {
            content.onTapGesture {
                editingModel = EditingModel(tag: "model")
            }
        }
    }
}
```